# Window phone 8.1: Change Background Color of Button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm studying developing apps for window phone 8.1. And i have a problem when i try to change background color of a button. In Mainpage.xaml, i have following code:

```
<Button 
    Name="button" Background="Pink" 
    Click="OnClick">
    ClickMe1
 </Button>
```

Then i define OnClick event:`

```
 private void ClickMe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
}
```

but it didn't work because: The name 'Colors' does not exsit in the current context
I tried to fix

```
void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    button.Background = Brushes.Green;
}
```

but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8.1, **Colors** class is in **Windows.UI** namespace.

So you can set background of button like this:

```
button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
```